# Laravel - DB::rollBack() No hace efecto

Tags: laravel

Estoy utilizando transacciones en laravel pero el DB::rollBack() No hace efecto, al hacer la insercion en la base de datos la guarda sin ejecutar el commit incluso si ejecuto el rollBack(), este es mi codigo:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
DB::table('areas')->insert([ 'name' => 'area 1' ]);
DB::rollBack();
```

Tambien he probado con esto:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
   DB::table('areas')->insert([ 'name' => 'area 1' ]);
   throw new \Exception("error");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya solucione el error, el problema era que estaba usando como motor en mysql MyISAM en vez de InnoDB para las tablas.